# how to add ssh public key to a specific git repo

Tags: git, ubuntu, ssh, public-key-encryption, repository

I have a git repo, i connect via root to push and pull. I have another user i'd like to have access to my repo.

I have got him to create me a public key file for me to add to my servers `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

How do i then restrict him from having access to my entire server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `git-shell` as their login shell in `/etc/passwd`, as [documented here](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-4.html). Doing this, you can have a single account dedicated to `git` access for you both.

The more complicated solution is to use something like [gitolite](https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite) to manage access to a collection of repos. I've used it and it's a bit of a pain to set up at first, but it works well and is currently maintained.

Alternatively, [Bitbucket](http://bitbucket.org) hosts unlimited private Git repos for free. You can both point your repos to Bitbucket as origin/master and collaborate there instead. This is what I do now.